# Internal plugin system and Modules in Ruby (Rails used as a framework)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a base lass and then load all sub classes (plugins) and process all of them via `each` loop. This is working example:

```
require 'set'

class Plugin
  # Keep the plugin list inside a set so we don't double-load plugins
  @plugins = Set.new

  def self.plugins
    @plugins
  end

  def self.register_plugins
    # Iterate over each symbol in the object space
    Object.constants.each do |klass|
      # Get the constant from the Kernel using the symbol
      const = Kernel.const_get(klass)
      # Check if the plugin has a super class and if the type is Plugin
      if const.respond_to?(:superclass) and const.superclass == Plugin
        @plugins << const
      end
    end
  end
end

class DogPlugin < Plugin

  def self.handle_command(cmd)
    p "Command received #{cmd}"
  end

end
class CatPlugin < Plugin

  def self.handle_command(cmd)
    p "Command received #{cmd}"
  end

end

Plugin.register_plugins

# Test that we can send a message to each plugin
Plugin.plugins.each do |plugin|
  plugin.handle_command('test')
end
```

This code sample works perfectly. Output is:

```
"Command received test"
"Command received test"
=> #<Set: {DogPlugin, CatPlugin}>
```

However, In my rails application, my custom implementations are in modules. Lets say I have an `A` module. In this case it doesn't work.

```
require 'set'

module A
  class Plugin
    @plugins = Set.new

    class << self
      attr_reader :plugins
    end

    def self.register_plugins
      # Iterate over each symbol in the object space
      Object.constants.each do |klass|
        # Get the constant from the Kernel using the symbol
        const = Kernel.const_get(klass)
        # Check if the plugin has a super class and if the type is Plugin
        if const.respond_to?(:superclass) && (const.superclass == A::Plugin)
          @plugins << const
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module A
  class MyAction < Plugin
    def self.handle_command(cmd)
      puts "Command received #{cmd}"
    end
   end
end

A::Plugin.register_plugins
A::Plugin.plugins.each do |plugin|
  plugin.handle_command('test')
end
```

`Set` is empty and nothing get executed. Why?

See live sample here: https://repl.it/repls/EllipticalDamagedCategory

There are other types of plugin samples on the net but they have to initialized one-by-one. This sample code loads all plugins and execute same method in all of them. I need this functionality with modules.

Comment: It's probably an issue with load order. What we have done at my company is make a  file in `config/initializers` which loads the files in the order they're needed.

Comment: At my sample, If I change order, it fails. I think sample is in good order. It has something to do with modules. Because when same example made without module `A` with same order, It works.

Comment: You know that [`Class#inherited`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Class.html#method-i-inherited) is a thing correct? Just seems like a better way to implement than to use a loop. [Updated Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/EllipticalDamagedCategory) using `inherited`

Comment: Ah. I see. I will use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'set'

module A
  class Plugin
    @plugins = Set.new

    def self.plugins
      @plugins
    end

    def self.register_plugins
      # Iterate over each symbol in the object space
      ::A.constants.each do |klass|
        # Get the constant from the Kernel using the symbol
        const = A.const_get(klass)
        puts const
        # Check if the plugin has a super class and if the type is Plugin

        if const.respond_to?(:superclass) && (const.superclass == Plugin)
          @plugins << const
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module A
  class MyAction < Plugin
    def self.handle_command(cmd)
      puts "Command received #{cmd}"
    end
   end
end

A::Plugin.register_plugins
A::Plugin.plugins.each do |plugin|
  plugin.handle_command('test')
end
```

Comment: I am very sorry to say this but i quite didn't understand that. Could you please post a sample based on above to wake me up? :/

Comment: I updated with a working version, you need to load constants of the module itself..

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask a quick question. I didn't want to open a new issue for this. When using standalone ruby it works, however, in Rails i think autoload feature breaks it. Even I explicitly require it, MyAction (my_action.rb) class does not found. Do you know anything about this? What might be the problem? (When I move MyAction to the same file with Plugin, it works).